# Yii2 mongodb upsert

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

[yiisoft/yii2-mongodb README](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md) tells, that we can insert data to mongodb with this code:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('somecollection');
$collection->insert($data_array);
```

But if we insert the same **_id** multiple times, we'll get duplicate exception. As far as I know, in mongo you should update data with "upsert:true" true (as said in [this book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf)). How to I write it, using **yii2-mongo** component? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/blob/cfb60d5d6dedd80f2bb9ee1f13a3edb906d920ef/Session.php

This is the only reference of upsert in the library in the repo. Looks like `writeSession()` sets upsert automatically. IIRC upsert tries to UPDATE and if that fails then INSERTs. I am not familiar with the library personally try

`$collection->update($data_array);`

But honestly Im just spit-balling about the repo's operation.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I need. The final version is: $collection->update(['_id' => $data['_id']], $data, ['upsert' => true]); Thank you!

Comment: Hazzah! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "updateAll"

`$options = ['upsert' => true];
YourMongodbModel::updateAll($attributes, $condition, $options);`